# How to verify if GPU is engaged to render video content in a web page?

Tags: gpu

Is it possible (with `top`or similar) to verify that a laptop's GPU is engaged when video is played from abcnews.go.com or similar?  The idea is that if the GPU is not engaged, then change the GPU settings and verify.

Comment: AFAIK, unlike on Windows, on Linux a dedicated GPU in a laptop cannot be used at the same time as the iGPU. Either one or the other, but not both at the same time.

Comment: (On Windows the drivers do some crazy magic to allow the dedicated GPU to render to the screenbuffer of the iGPU)

Comment: For nvidia graphics card (with nvidia binary driver installed) You can run `nvidia-smi -q` this will display processes that use the GPU f.ex. Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `nvidia-smi` to check if your players process is there.
As an example here is the output of `nvidia-smi` on my laptop showing both gnome-shell and the image processing software darktable using the GPU

[image]

If you wish to narrow down the output `nvidia-smi -q -d PIDS` should be your choice.

Detailed info here https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DCGM/docs/nvidia-smi-367.38.pdf